# ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError destroy is defined by Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4

```
def create
            omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
            authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
            if authentication
              flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
              sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
            elsif current_user
              current_user.authentication.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
              flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful"
              redirect_to authentication_url
            else
              user = User.new
              user.authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
              user.save!
              flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful"
              sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
            end
 end
```

This is the code for creating twitter authentication. However, at line 13,

```
user.authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      user.save!
```

raises the error.

```
destroy is defined by Active Record
```

I didn't find any help on the web.
I'm following railscast 236. Rails version 4.0.0, ruby version 2.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might have used scaffold, instead of nifty:scaffold

Answer (score 3):

Check your tables and make sure you don't have columns names such as

```
index, create, destroy, delete
```

Comment: I had the same problem as the questioner which as you pointed out in the comments is because I used scaffold instead of nifty:scaffold. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the railscast [235](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) there is an error when generating scaffold for authentication: I also had the same error and after dropping the table, modifying the authentication migration and running `rails db:drop:all` followed by `rails db:migrate`, everything comes to normal.